# Rewind stream pointer to the line back

Tags: c++

I have an input file stream and a string declared as:

```
std::ifstream finput;
std::string tmp_string;
```

and I read lines iteratively using `std::getline(finput, tmp_string);`

The question is: how to rewind the stream pointer so that after that rewind the second call of `std::getline(finput, tmp_string);` would return the same result (as one step before)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Once you've read the line, it's too late.  You can't go back to a
position you haven't memorized.  If you need this, the only solution is
to call `finput.gtell()` before the `getline`, and then seek to what it
returned.

Comment: Well, makes sense. But what's actually wrong with seeking to `current position - last string size`?

Comment: Two things.  The most obvious is that the numeric value isn't right anyway: `getline` will also extract the trailing `'\n'`.  More importantly, perhaps, is the fact that if the `streampos` passed to `gseek` has not been obtained by a previously successful call to `tellg` on the same file, the effects of the seek are undefined.

Comment: @zerkms: one reason is that when reading a file in text mode, file offsets are magical mysterious things because the implementation is allowed to play tricks under the hood as it translates line breaks or other implementation-specific control characters. So the C standard plays safe, and says you can only seek to a "real" position, i.e. a position that the stream has been in before. You can't make up a number and seek to it in a text file, so that the implementation isn't required to support e.g. the current position being between the `\r` and `\n`.

Comment: ... There may be additional C++-only reasons for applying the same rule to file streams, I'm not certain.

Comment: @SteveJessop That's what I'm wondering myself.  C does allow arbitrary `fseek` on a file opened in binary most; C++ doesn't allow `seek(streampos)`.